# How to generate a URL with Attribute Routing based on the controller template and Action Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributerouting

I have the following URL template in the `IdeasController`:

```
[Controller]
[Route("/gemeente/{municipalityName}/election/{electionId}/ideas/"Name = "Ideas")]

public class IdeasController : Controller
```

I also have this `Action` with route template:

```
[Route("theme/{themeId}/",Name = "GetTheme")]
public IActionResult GetTheme(int themeId)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get theme----------------------------");
    
    IEnumerable<Idea> ideas = _ideasManager.GetIdeasByTheme(themeId);
    GeneralTheme theme = _themeManager.GetGeneralTheme(themeId);
    IdeasByThemeDto ideasByThemeDto = new IdeasByThemeDto
    {
        Ideas = ideas,
        Theme = theme
    };
    ViewBag["Title"] = "Ideas by theme: " + theme.Name;
    
    return View("IdeasByTheme", ideasByThemeDto);
}
```

How can I generate a URL to arrive at `gemeente/Dendermonde/election/1/ideas/theme/2` in the view?

Concrete example in view:

I have a collection of ideas, each idea has a theme with a `themeId`.

I want to generate a URL that appends the current URL (`/gemeente/{municipalityName}/election/{electionId}/ideas/`) with the theme id (`theme/{themeId}`), which basically combines the two ("Ideas" and "GetTheme") templates together.

In the view:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("GetTheme22", new { themeId = Model.Theme.Id })  //empty string
```

Note: municipality name and election id should also be dynamically inserted, based on the previous request.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @jdweng what do I need to change based on the documentation?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld review [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#url-generation-concepts) to get a better understanding or URL generation

Comment: @Nkosi any hint as to where I'm wrong? Reading the article you provided only made me more confused tbh

Comment: Show an example of where you are trying to generate and use the desired url

Comment: @Nkosi I edited my question, saw your answer, but how can `MunicipalitName` and `electionId` be dynamcally inserted?

Comment: Well where were you planning on getting those values from? Are they part of the view model like the themeId

Comment: @Nkosi Good question, I thought if the request has the information, it can somehow be included

Comment: Then extract it from where ever you stored it in the request

Comment: @Nkosi so adding it to the viewbag or dto would be a good practice?

Comment: Yes. it needs to be strored somewhere to be passed on to the view. ViewBag or model will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the shown route templates you could generate a link using `Url.RouteUrl`:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GetTheme", new {municipalityName="Dendermonde", electionId=1, themeId=2})">Get Themes</a>
```

which would resolve to

```
<a href="gemeente/Dendermonde/election/1/ideas/theme/2">Get Themes</a>
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core - Generate URLs by route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#generate-urls-by-route)

> how can `MunicipalitName` and `electionId` be dynamically inserted.

How that information is passed to the view is up to personal preference and factors specific to the use case.

Here, the following extracts the controller template parameters from the `ViewBag` *assuming it was stored there from the previous request*

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GetTheme", new {
    municipalityName=ViewBag["MunicipalitName"], 
    electionId=ViewBag["electionId"], 
    themeId=Model.Theme.Id})">Get Themes</a>
```

While the following assumes everything was stored in the Model

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GetTheme", new {
    municipalityName=Model.MunicipalitName, 
    electionId=Model.ElectionId, 
    themeId=Model.Theme.Id})">Get Themes</a>
```